# How to restric data to insert in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 groups in one table called `GroupA,GroupB,GroupC,GroupD`.The Column should accept only 5 values, not more . How can I achieve this in MySQL ?

```
    GroupA GroupB
    aaa     fff 
    bbb     ggg
    ccc     iii
    ddd   
    eee
```

Now the 6th person should not entered into GroupA

Comment: I dont know to restrict values in mysql .

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take in MySQL.  The first is to use a trigger to validate the values.

The second is to create a reference table that has the five legal values in it and use a foreign key constraint to ensure the value.  Something like this:

```
create table GroupA_value (
     GroupA varchar(255) not null primary key
);

create table t (
     . . .
     GroupA varchar(255) not null preferences GroupA_value(GroupA)
)
```

Personally, I would use identifiers rather than the actual value, but you don't give much information about the overall structure.

Most other databases support the `check` constraint which makes this much easier.  MySQL accepts the syntax, but doesn't do the check.

Comment: Actually it's a quiz game. So in each team only 5 persons should be there and I have to calculate the score of each groups also .